# 404 Error with Karma/Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I have removed all $httpbackend stuff from angular mocks in an attempt to get Karma to test with real $http calls. If, inside my Mocha test I do:

it('should return something', function(done) {

```
 inject(function($http) {
    $http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/hello', {}).success(function(err) {
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

The above works fine - but I have to specify the host/post. Now I have a service that does the exact same call within itself - but it only has /api/hello - no server since it's local as far as my Angular app is concerned.

```
it('should return something', function(done) {

  $scope.$apply(function() {
    myService.doCall(function(res) {
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

That does not works and gives me WARN [web-server]: 404: /api/hello

Here's the service:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('myService', function($http) {
  return{    
    doCall: function(callback) {
      $http.get('/api/hellos').success(function(data) {
        callback(data);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

I have tried setting host/port in karma.conf but that doesn't seem to do anything. Proxies don't seem to work either.

Suggestions as to where to set my host/port?

Or alternate suggestions on Karma + real $http?  There is an angular-spec gist floating around but that seems broken so I am trying to do the same.

Comment: What's myService.doCall? What does it do?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - edited post - does same thing